# Pass json array from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I wast some hours searching solutions for my issue and I couldn't find an answer.

I'm making a search on same page and for that, I'm using Jquery, AJAX and PHP.

The array from php still return undefined.

**PHP code:**

```
$i=0;        
while($eee = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $array[$i][1] = $eee['ex'];
    $array[$i][2] = $eee['ex'];
    $array[$i][3] = $eee['ex'];
    $array[$i][4] = $eee['ex'];
    $array[$i][5] = $eee['ex'];
    $array[$i][6] = $eee['ex'];
    $array[$i][7] = $eee['ex'];
    $i = $i + 1;
}
json_encode($array)
```

**AJAX and JQUERY**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('submit', '#FormData', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data[1]);
                }
            }); 
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Thanks for any help here ;)

Comment: Is that all you have in the PHP file?  Are you returning anything or `echo json_encode()` anything?

Comment: Is the important code, I remove name of tables and db connection. I know the query a correct array cuz I've printed_r the array to see if it was.

Comment: **Most important** - use the webbrowsers console to debug and show us what you could find out. It makes helping you ten thousand percent easier.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, I know it and I'm using

Comment: @Ruben but you are not sharing the information with us but still expect help...

Comment: @DanFromGermany on console has no error or aditional information

Comment: You are starting with index `0` but in the Javascript you print index `1` of the data. Why not just `console.log(data)` to see what comes through then go on? Why not show what is getting transfered through web console and tell us? You are not providing information although several people asked you several times. Instead of telling us for example if you get data, you let us guess. Why you let us guess the problem, when you can look up 99% of the problem in the console??

Comment: Is it a PHP error, Javascript error, problem with Ajax... things you can look up, but no, you let us guess. Example of data? No, you let us guess. So ignorant.

Answer (score -1):

in your php file use echo  `json_encode($array);`

in your jquery

```
 type: 'json',
method:'post'
```

,

Comment: also your json_encode needs to be  `echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: when I add dataType:'json',
    method:'post', it didn't has sucess on ajax. Can u tell me why?